# Installing Visual Paradigm for UML gives: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: java.awt.Container

Tags: ubuntu, installation, java, uml

I have recently downloaded Visual Paradigm for UML onto my system (Ubuntu 12.0.4 LTS).

When I tried to install it, it failed. Here is the stacktrace:

```
Unpacking JRE ...
Preparing JRE ...
Starting Installer ...
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: java.awt.Container
    at com.install4j.runtime.installer.frontend.headless.AbstractHeadlessScreenExecutor.init(Unknown Source)
    at com.install4j.runtime.installer.frontend.headless.ConsoleScreenExecutor.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at com.install4j.runtime.installer.frontend.headless.InstallerConsoleScreenExecutor.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at com.install4j.runtime.installer.Installer.getScreenExecutor(Unknown Source)
    at com.install4j.runtime.installer.Installer.runInProcess(Unknown Source)
    at com.install4j.runtime.installer.Installer.main(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at com.exe4j.runtime.LauncherEngine.launch(Unknown Source)
    at com.install4j.runtime.launcher.Launcher.main(Unknown Source)
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: java.awt.Component
    at javax.swing.ImageIcon.<clinit>(Unknown Source)
    at com.install4j.runtime.installer.frontend.GUIHelper.loadIcon(Unknown Source)
    at com.install4j.runtime.installer.frontend.GUIHelper.<clinit>(Unknown Source)
    at com.install4j.runtime.installer.helper.InstallerUtil.reportException(Unknown Source)
    at com.install4j.runtime.installer.Installer.main(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at com.exe4j.runtime.LauncherEngine.launch(Unknown Source)
    at com.install4j.runtime.launcher.Launcher.main(Unknown Source)
```

It appears that the installer can't find a class in the WT library. I can't see how how that can be possible. Does anyone know what is causing this, and how I may fix it?

**[Update]**

```
java version "1.6.0_24"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (IcedTea6 1.11.5) (6b24-1.11.5-0ubuntu1~12.04.1)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 20.0-b12, mixed mode)
```

Comment: What Java version/variant do you have installed? Try installing Sun/Oracle Java if you have something else.

Comment: @DanielBeck: Please see my updated questiojn

Comment: I am not sure, but maybe server VM does not have GUI toolkit in it?

Comment: @madhead: No, I am installing on my desktop, which is not a headless server.